# How to effectiv convert utf-8-mac to utf

Tags: macos, utf-8, iconv

I must convert regularly a file which contains uft-8-mac strings to uft-8. I started to do the job with iconv.
How ever iconv throws an error, if there was too many lines which must be converted.
Here is a script to reproduce the bug

```
#!/bin/zsh
set -eu

for i in {1..1000}; do
  echo "$i:äöüß@€" >> /tmp/xx
  iconv -f utf-8-mac -t utf-8 /tmp/xx > /dev/null
done
```

Obviously I can split the file, but I get then really a lot of files.

Has anyone another workaround or tool? Or a code example in golang?

I tried

```
func main() {
    dat, err := os.ReadFile(".backup_files.unconv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    output := ".backup_files.goconv"
    w, err := os.Create(output)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Can't create %s, %v", output, err)
    }
    defer closeFile(w)
    wc := norm.NFC.Writer(w)
    defer wc.Close()
    wc.Write(dat)
}
```

But it differs from iconv result.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What the difference and usage of encodings UTF-8 and UTF-8-MAC in iconv?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346453/)

Comment: This is definitely a bug in the Apple version of iconv. I haven't been able to nail down the root cause, but it's not about the size of the file per se. It's that the 4096-byte buffer size happens to split a character. It fails at the point that it passes `:\xc3` to the converter. This is the colon followed by the first byte of the ä, but without the second byte. If you play with the boundaries (add one byte at the beginning of the file for example), you can move the failure around. I would open a feedback with Apple.

Comment: The source code is here: https://opensource.apple.com/source/libiconv/libiconv-59/  You want to look in `utf8mac.h` for the relevant Apple code. To build it, just remove the `#include` line in base.xcconfig, and change GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL to 0.

Comment: That said, when you say the Go code "differs from iconv result," what's the difference? Your Go code feels like a good direction to get around Apple's bug. Another obnoxious way you could work around it is to read the file in <4096 byte chunks, making sure that you finish on a character boundary, then pass each chunk to iconv. utf-8-mac is legitimate UTF-8 (it's just NFD with some exceptions), so you should be able to parse it in Go, character by character, until the buffer is close to 4096, then pass the buffer to iconv.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis and tips. I had given apple feedback, so they could fix it. Unfortunately they don't have a bug tracker:-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an appropriate solution:
You can use the [`uconv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uconv) utility from [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/). [Normalization](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/transforms/normalization/) is achieved through transliteration (`-x`).

On Debian, Ubuntu and other derivatives, `uconv` is in the `libicu-dev` package. On Fedora, Red Hat and other derivatives, and in BSD ports, it's in the `icu` package.

Thanks to [Gilles 'SO- stop being evil'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90164/22610)